# Is this equals legal?

Tags: java, equals

I've came across this piece of code. I have never seen an equals implemented in such a way. What strike me was that it is really "neat", in the sense that is only takes one line of boilerplate.

However, the fact I have never seen this approach before make me suspicious. According to the contract of Java equals and hashCode, is the following implementation legal?

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
  return this == o || o instanceof DetailsPageTrackingRequest 
  && this.hashCode() == o.hashCode();
}

@Override
public int hashCode()
{
  //java.util.Objects
  return Objects.hash(pageTrackingRequest, searchId, productId);
}
```

Comment: Well, you check if this is the same instance or if this is an instance ( and so if it is not null in the same occasion) and then compare the hash. This seems not a bad idea but I might miss something

Comment: Also make sure you really want to use `instanceof` and not `getClass()`- see http://stackoverflow.com/q/596462/2513200 for arguments to choose one or the other. It is very easy to accidentally break the symmetry when using `instanceof`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably a bad idea for the reasons already stated in other answers.

As for the "legal" aspects, the [Contract of Object.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) states

> The equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null object references:
>
> - It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x) should return true.
> - It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.
> - It is transitive: for any non-null reference values x, y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true, then x.equals(z) should return true.
> - It is consistent: for any non-null reference values x and y, multiple invocations of x.equals(y) consistently return true or consistently return false, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the objects is modified.
> - For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.

Step by step:

- reflexive: Yes, due to `this == o`
- symmetric: due to the use of `instanceof`, we would need to look at all super- and subclasses to be sure
- transitive: depends on the symmetry-requirement, otherwise Yes
- consistent: Yes
- `x.equals(null)` should return false: Yes, due to `instanceof`

So from a purely legal point of view, it depends on whether other implementations accross your inheritance-hierarchy violate the symmetry and transitivity - see the answers to [Any reason to prefer getClass() over instanceof when generating .equals()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/596462/2513200).

But aside from that, given the fact that `hashCode` is not required to produce different values for non-equivalent instances, it is usually not a good way to define equality.

---

An example:

A immutable point class with two fields `x` and `y`

```
class Point {
    final int x;
    final int y

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

-> there are `2^32 * 2^32 = 2^64` distinct states, but only `2^32` possible hashcodes. This means that there are lots of points that would be considered equal according to your implementation of `equals`.

---

Also see this example [equals and hashCode: Is Objects.hash method broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13785353/2513200) for someone stumbling over a hash-collision for hashes created with `Objects.hash` with `Strings`.

Answer (score 5):

It's up to you do define the criteria according to which two instances of a class are considered equal to each other.

However, you should consider that different combinations of the `pageTrackingRequest`, `searchId` & `productId` properties might result in the same hash code, and you might not want to consider such different combinations as equal to each other. It might make more sense for `equals` to require that all 3 properties are equal to each other respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the property values individually rather than just checking the `hashCode`. There is a chance that two completely different `objects` result in same `hashCode` that are not equal.

Also, `equals` should not solely rely on `hashCode`, e.g. if `hashCode` method gets changed to the following:

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return 31;
}
```

`equals` method would start returning `true` for all the objects which should not be the case.

Comment: ...and this would be a perfectly legal implementation for `hashCode` (but a very bad one, of course).

Answer (score 0):

This approach is wrong. Hash code equality is not conclusive because non-equal objects may have the same hash. It's an engineered-in bug.